# MATLAB - Load data file with a string file name

Tags: matlab-load

I am writing a Matlab program that loads a data file created in another C++ program.

```
    planet = input('What is the name of your planet? ', 's')
    data_file = strcat(planet, '.dat')
    load(data_file);
    data_file;
    x = data_file(:,1);
    y = data_file(:,2);
    plot (x,y,'r*')
```

The program takes the name of the planet as the user input, then concatenates ".dat" to the end of the planet name. This gives, for example, "earth.dat," which is the name of the file created by the other C++ program.

I have made sure that the data file being loaded is in the correct folder; however, MATLAB still gives an error when I run the program.

What is the correct command for loading this file?

Thank you!

Comment: what error does it give? what format is earth.dat in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this instead:

```
planet = input('What is the name of your planet? ', 's')
filename=[num2str(planet) '.dat'];
data_file=load(filename);
x = data_file(:,1);
y = data_file(:,2);
plot (x,y,'r*')
```