# MATLAB load not working with variable filename

Tags: matlab

I try to load a .mat file in MATLAB R2016a. However, when I make the filename variable, it fails with

> Error using load
>   Unable to read file 'filename'. No such file or directory.

The [documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html#btm0etn-1-filename) for R2018a states that the filename has to be

> specified as a character vector or string

which i did. I searched for similar questions on SO, but they were all due to typing errors, e.g. [Error using load; Unable to read file matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661205/error-using-load-unable-to-read-file-matlab)

Code for reproduction:

```
clear all
mat1 = magic(5);
save mat1
clear mat1
load mat1 % working
clear mat1
filename = 'mat1.mat'; % tried with/without .mat
load filename % not working
```

- What is the cause of this error?
- How to resolve it?

Comment: Could the down-voters please give a reason? It took me some time to figure this out; it was not answered here before; it is encouraged to answer own questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but this same question has been asked very often.

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13692907/7328782

Comment: Thanks for the response. I must have used the wrong search terms for not finding the first two examples. The third one seems to be a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

After further research I found that the [documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html#btm0etn-1-filename) (R2018a) also states

> load filename is the command form of the syntax. [...]
>   Do not use command form when any of the inputs, such as filename, are variables.

This answers my second question. Use:

```
load(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

The *cause* of this error is that the statement:

```
load filename
```

internally evaluates to:

```
load('filename.mat')
```

in order to support command-form statements statements like `load mat1` in your example. It fails because the file `filename.mat` clearly does not exist.

The function form is always safer, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, if this is really the cause, something like `filename = 'mat1';load filename` (without .mat) should work - but it doesn't.

Comment: @David `load filename` evaluates to  `load('filename.mat')`; not `load('mat1.mat')` and hence it *shouldn't* work.

Comment: The last sentence in the answer is opinion based though

Comment: Yeah, @SardarUsama I made a change to that sentence. But is there any situation where the command form is safer?

Comment: If a person doesn't know the syntax,  he should read the documentation. If someone is randomly trying to use a function, he shouldn't expect it safe.

Comment: Of course. But I meant function form is safer as opposed to the command form in terms of syntax.

Comment: No it is not. These are equally safe if a person reads the doc instead of randomly trying to use it

Comment: Right, okay. Understood.